# Unknown plugin "external-helpers" specified in "base" at 0, what does this even mean?

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm building a glimmerjs application like this:

```
ember build --environment test
```

And the error is:

```
Build failed.
Build Error (RollupWithDependencies)

Unknown plugin "external-helpers" specified in "base" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "/Users/givanse/code/pretender"

Stack Trace and Error Report: /var/folders/6y/8lyh7xn954v714ktlj5nmndw0000gn/T/error.dump.099d52a5b4b21a993722a86f9f2693ec.log
```

In the log:

```
nodeAnnotation: RollupWithDependencies                                                                                
  - nodeName: RollupWithDependencies                                                                                      
  - originalErrorMessage: Unknown plugin "external-helpers" specified in "base" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "/Users/givanse/code/pretender"
  - stack: Error: Unknown plugin "external-helpers" specified in "base" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "/Users/givanse/code/pretender"
    at error (/Users/givanse/code/project-pulse/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:170:12)
    at /Users/givanse/code/project-pulse/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:8937:6                                        
    at <anonymous>
```

That stack trace corresponds to the `transform` function here [rollup/blob/v0.41.6/src/utils/transform.js#L95](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/blob/a96a923d631b9d2c471137542b9c4f578b8faa53/src/utils/transform.js#L95)

Adding some logging there shows that the error happens when `babel.transform` is invoked.

Posting not hoping for an answer, but just a clue or theory.

Comment: so looks like this is missing somewhere https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-external-helpers